# arrays declaration and addressing

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I have a few straightforward questions:-

1. Is the following correct according to a normal c++ compiler?

   ```
   int arr[3][4];
   void func(int *a, int m, int n)
   {
    int i,j;
    cin>>i>>j; 
    cout<< a[i*n + j]; //is this way of addressing correct provided 0<=i<m and 0<=j<n
   } 

   int main()
   {
    func((int*)arr, 3,4);
   }
   ```
2. If the bounds of an array strictly has to be a constant expression, why doesn't the following generate compiler errors?

   ```
   int func(int m, int n)
   {
    int arr[m][n]; //m and n are not known until run time
   }
   ```

Comment: Under a strict reading of the Standard it's generally not possible to use a multidimensional array as if it were a flat array (beyond the first few elements). This is something that is routinely ignored however, to the extent that I didn't really find any SO answer that mentions it -- other than [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7273599/726300) by yours truly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the following correct according to a normal c++ compiler?

Yes, because the Standard specifies that even arrays with more than 1 dimensions are contigous in memory. **BUT!** You're misunderstanding array indexing and length a bit - i and j have to be *strictly less* than 3 and 4, respectively. The 3 and 4 are the sizes of the array in its two dimensions, and *not* the maximal possible subscripts.

> If the bounds of an array strictly has to be a constant expression, why doesn't the following generate compiler errors?

Maybe you're using a compiler that supports this as an extension (think of GCC, Clang, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually **undefined behavior** as you access the array `a` using uninitialized values of i and j. Otherwise, if you are using calculating the array index correctly (within the bounds), then it's valid.

You might be using gcc extension for [variable length array](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length) in your case.