# Fill a C++ bidimensional array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having a simple issue with `std :: fill`.

First I define a 2-dimensions array of pairs.

```
const int NMAX = 13;                                                             
typedef pair<int, set<int>> solution;                                            
solution memo[NMAX][NMAX];
```

I assume that at that stage my array is initialized with default pair constructor. Then, I would like to initialize this array without relying on a nested loop. What I am doing is this:

```
solution s;                                                                  
s.first = -1;                                                                                                 
std::fill( &memo[0][0], &memo[0][0] + sizeof(memo), s);
```

But I get a bus error... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _`solution memo[NMAX][NMAX];`_ why not `vector<vector<solution>> memo;` instead? Also `array<array<solution,MAX>,MAX> memo;` should be fine.

Comment: `sizeof` is not the number of elements, but the number of chars (bytes).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not the same. The data in the vector of vectors is not contiguous.

Comment: @juanchopanza what ? vector provide contiguous memory location.

Comment: @FélixCantournet: we are talking about `vector<vector<T>>` which have several non-contiguous buffers of contiguous `T`s.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes ok. the top-level vector only garantees that the vector<T> objects are contiguous which you don't really care about. Damn you indirection !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your end pointer is wrong, you mean:

```
std::fill(&memo[0][0], &memo[0][0] + sizeof(memo) / sizeof (solution), s);
```

as `sizeof(memo)` is `NMAX * NMAX * sizeof (solution)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's something about this being UB, because it accesses the outer array out of bounds. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269099/may-i-treat-a-2d-array-as-a-contiguous-1d-array

Comment: Technically this is UB; it is doing the same as `memo[0][NMAX] = s; memo[0][NMAX+1] = s;` etc.

Comment: @juanchopanza The relevant section in the standard is not clearly worded. It's not clear whether "an element of the array object" can be an `int` in this case. If you say "No it can't" then many commonly accepted techniques become illegal (e.g. iterating over `memo` with a `char *`). My interpretation is that it's legal to use an `int *` to iterate over the array, so long as you form it with `(int *)&memo` or `(int *)&memo[0]`, so that "the array object" unambiguously means `memo`, and not a sub-object of `memo`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb That used to be my interpretation (that it is OK) and then I got convinced otherwise. Now I'm not sure anymore. IIRC there was a defect report about this, but I don't know what happened with that.

Comment: @juanchopanza re. the DRs, I don't think anyone on the committee wants to touch it :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually we can do all of this a lot easier with `std::vector`:

```
typedef pair<int, set<int>> solution; 
solution s;                                                                  
s.first = -1;
std::vector<std::vector<solution>> memo(NMAX, std::vector<solution>(NMAX, s));
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/oZRr52)

Unless you have some restriction against using a `std::vector`, it's going to be much easier to work with rather than doing a bunch of pointer math.

**Edit:** It's not the worst idea to use `std::array` either, like [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147110/fill-a-c-bidimensional-array-of-objects#comment46516738_29147110) suggested. You can avoid writing the internal loop to perform the fill yourself with a `std::for_each` as follows:

```
std::array<std::array<solution, NMAX>, NMAX> memo;
solution s;                                                                  
s.first = -1;
std::for_each(std::begin(memo), std::end(memo), [&s](std::array<solution,NMAX>& next){next.fill(s);})
```

[Demo 2](http://ideone.com/z4uiyD)

**Edit 2:** If you're really masochistic and want to compute [row][column] indices yourself, then you can use a single `std::array<solution, NMAX*NMAX>` and take advantage of `std::begin()` and `std::end()` to call `std::fill`:

```
std::array<solution, NMAX*NMAX> memo;
solution s;                                                                  
s.first = -1;
std::fill(std::begin(memo),std::end(memo), s);
```

[Demo 3](http://ideone.com/DhDna1)