# Add a matrix of 2x2 into a vector in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I am trying to fill a vector with a matrix of values in c++. I'm not very self confident with this procedure (I don't know well about pointers and I don't know if I need it here) however I am trying this

```
int auxMat[gray.rows][gray.cols];
vector<int> collectionSum;
collectionSum.push_back(auxMat);
```

When I try to compile I receive an error which says

invalid arguments 'Candidates are: void push_back(const int &)

Can anyone tell me wether it's possible to do, how can I solve it?

I read something about erasing cache memory, changing my eclipse compiler, my c++ version, however I don't think the problem is so big.

Comment: You have to `push_back()` the values individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot push back a matrix into a vector. What you can do is preallocate memory for your vector (for speeding things up) then use the [`std::vector<>::assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) member function to "copy" from the matrix into the vector:

```
vector<int> collectionSum(gray.rows * gray.cols); // reserve memory, faster
collectionSum.assign(*auxMat, *auxMat + gray.rows * gray.cols);
```

This should be pretty fast. Otherwise, you can push back each individual element in a loop.

**EDIT**

See [May I treat a 2D array as a contiguous 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269099/may-i-treat-a-2d-array-as-a-contiguous-1d-array) for some technicalities regarding possible undefined behaviour (thanks @juanchopanza for the comment). I believe the code is safe, due to the fact that the storage of the matrix is contiguous.

Comment: I think there's a thing about out of bounds access which makes this technically UB, even though it is hard to think of an implementation where this wouldn't work. I'll see if I can find some links.

Comment: @juanchopanza actually that's exactly what I was thinking right now... since we do out of bounds, however we have contiguous storage.

Comment: There's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269099/may-i-treat-a-2d-array-as-a-contiguous-1d-array

Comment: @juanchopanza hmm, still not 100% convinced whether the code is 100% safe or not.

Comment: Thanks, @vsoftco. I will try this one... However I already did something with a vector of a vector of a vector of integer (long and slow thing) since I didn't know how to get to the result.

Comment: @DiegoAlejandroGómezPardo you should avoid vector of vector if possible, since as you observed things are slow due to cache misses (non-contiguous storage). You can use a "flattened" vector, and emulate 2D-3D access. However, the method above works.

Answer (score 0):

Because the array auxMat is continuous in memory, you can just copy it directly from memory into your vector. Here, you are telling the vector constructor to copy from the start of auxMat until its end in memory using pointer arithmetic:

```
std::vector<int> collectionSum(auxMat, auxMat + (gray.rows * gray.cols));
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I read your question as being a 1D array (int*) rather than a 2D (int**) array. I honestly recommend switching over to a 1D array because often it is faster and easier to work with. Depending on whether your using row-first order or column-first order, you can access the element you want by:

```
elem = y * width + x;    // for row-first order
elem = x * height + y;   // for column-first order
```

For instance:

```
// Create a 3x3 matrix but represent it continuously as a 1D array
const int A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
const unsigned width = 3;
const unsigned height = 3;
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
       printf("%d ", A[y * width + x]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```