# Access to elements of array of arrays using common iterator

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, language-lawyer

Is it *undefined behaviour* in C++ to access elements in adjacent arrays as in following code?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int a[10][10];
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout< decltype(a) >::value, "!");
    std::fill(std::begin(*std::begin(a)), std::end(*std::prev(std::end(a))), 0);
    struct B { int b[10]; };
    B b[10];
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout< decltype(b) >::value, "!");
    std::fill(std::begin(std::begin(b)->b), std::end(std::prev(std::end(b))->b), 0);
}
```

Technically I think for POD-types it is legal to access underlying memory in any manner one want, but what about `std::*` stuff?

What if I change all `begin/end` to `rbegin/rend`?

Comment: In the second case, I don't think it's safe ( https://ideone.com/DyHhgA ) In the first, I don't know.

Comment: It is never good to mix c-style arrays `int a[10][10];` with c++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is UB.

From [[basic.compound]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3):

> Every value of pointer type is one of the following:
>
> - a pointer to an object or function (the pointer is said to point to the object or function), or
> - a pointer past the end of an object ([expr.add]), or
> - the null pointer value ([conv.ptr]) for that type, or
> - an invalid pointer value.
>
> A value of a pointer type that is a pointer to or past the end of an object represents the address of the first byte in memory ([intro.memory]) occupied by the object or the first byte in memory after the end of the storage occupied by the object, respectively. *[ Note:* A pointer past the end of an object ([expr.add]) is not considered to point to an unrelated object of the object's type that might be located at that address. A pointer value becomes invalid when the storage it denotes reaches the end of its storage duration; see [basic.stc]. *— end note ]*

And [[expr.add]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4):

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the expression P points to element x[i] of an array object x with n elements,86 the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value j) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element x[i+j] if 0≤i+j≤n; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. Likewise, the expression P - J points to the (possibly-hypothetical) element x[i−j] if 0≤i−j≤n ; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So `&a[0][0] + 10` is a "pointer past the end of an object", it's the past the end pointer of the first array. You cannot add one more to that pointer - there is no defined behavior for this case.

A pointer cannot be *both* a "past the end" pointer *and* a "pointer to object" (interpreting `&a[0][0] + 10` as if it were `&a[1][0]`). It's one or the other.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269099/may-i-treat-a-2d-array-as-a-contiguous-1d-array) just came to my attention.  Not sure what we should ask for them to be merged or just do a dupe closure.  I'm inclined to have it dupe closed to this if it isn't merged.