# Multi-Dimensional Arrays in Memory

Tags: c++, arrays

I am wondering if the C++ standard guarantees that multidimensional arrays (not dynamically allocated) are flattened into a 1D array of exactly the same space. For example, if I have

```
char x[100];
char y[10][10];
```

Would these both be equivalent? I'm aware that most compilers would flatten `y`, but is this actually guaranteed to happen? Reading section 11.3.4 Arrays of the C++ Standard, I cannot actually find anywhere that guarantees this.

The C++ standard guarantees that `y[i]` follows immediately after `y[i-1]`. Since `y[i-1]` is 10 characters long, then, logically speaking, `y[i]` should take place 10 characters later in memory; however, could a compiler pad `y[i-1]` with extra characters to keep `y[i]` aligned?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish with this?  Accessing `y[0][10]` will be UB.

Comment: Sounds like what you are really asking is if you can iterate a 2d array as if it is a 1d one.  The answer to that is legally no, but most/all implementations allow it since it is the only reasonable behavior. Very related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269099/may-i-treat-a-2d-array-as-a-contiguous-1d-array

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm My question isn't specifically about using the 2D array as a 1D, but how it is stored in memory. As an example, if I want to make a 10x10 board, then is it better to use a 1D array or a 2D array, in terms of space requirements.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica That post seems to have different answers. The accepted answer seems to imply it's up to interpretation, whereas the most voted answer says its _indirectly guaranteed_, and it is not UB, but I cannot find where this is "indirectly guaranteed" in the standard.

Comment: @ChrisMM The standard guarantees the arrays are contiguous and there is no padding.  That's why it will work.  The answer by xskxzr on that Q&A is the correct one though as you can't legally iterate from one row of the array to another one.  That is dictated by the pointer addition rules.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Where does it say there is no padding, especially for multiple dimensions? From what I can tell, it says that `y[i-1]` must precede `y[i]`, but this does not (to me) mean that there are not dummy bytes between `y[i-1]` and `y[i]`. From what I know, a compiler would pad `char z[5]` with 3 bytes to maintain 64-bit alignment, if the next value is a 64-bit number for example, or maybe 1 byte for a 32-bit value. Why could it not do this for multi-dimensional arrays, since they are arrays of arrays.  Sorry, I am just trying to understand where there is a guaranty.

Comment: @ChrisMM See: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.array#6

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Not trying to be difficult, but I don't see that as guaranteeing that there's no padding added to an array. That specifies that there's no padding between `y[i-1]` and `y[i]`, but if `y[i-1]` takes up `sizeof(char[10])+2` bytes, then there's still no additional padding between array elements, which would comply by the standard. If I have `char x[5]; int y[5]` then the compiler is free to add padding after the first array, so why can it not for the multi-dimensional array?

Comment: @ChrisMM I've added an answer to hopefully clear this all up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is found in [[dcl.array]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.array#6)

> An object of type “array of N U” contains a contiguously allocated non-empty set of N subobjects of type U, known as the elements of the array, and numbered 0 to N-1.

What this states is that if you have an array like `int arr[10]` then to have 10 `int`'s that are contiguous in memory.  This definition works recursively though so if you have

```
int arr[5][10]
```

then what you have is an array of 5 `int[10]` arrays.  If we apply the definition from above then we know that the 5 `int[10]` arrays are contiguous and then `int[10]`'s themselves are contiguous so all 50 `int`'s are contiguous.  So yes, a 2d array look just like a 1d array in memory since really that is what they are.

This does not mean you can get a pointer to `arr[0][0]` and iterate to `arr[4][9]` with it.  Per [[expr.add]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add#4)

> When an expression J that has integral type is added to or subtracted from an expression P of pointer type, the result has the type of P.
>
> - If P evaluates to a null pointer value and J evaluates to 0, the result is a null pointer value.
> - Otherwise, if P points to an array element i of an array object x with n elements ([dcl.array]), the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value j) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element i+j of x if 0≤i+j≤n and the expression P - J points to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element i−j of x if 0≤i−j≤n.
> - Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

What this states is that if you have a pointer to an array, then the valid indices you can add to it are `[0, array_size]`.  So if you did

```
int * it = &arr[0][0]
```

then what `it` points to is the first element of the first array which means you can legally only increment `it` to `it + 10` since that is the past then end element of the first array.  Going into the second array is UB even though they are contiguous.

Comment: Sorry, I still have the one question here: does `int[10]` guarantee that it is `sizeof(int) * 10` with absolutely no padding on the end? Are padding rules only for distinct variables?

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes.  Arrays are not allowed to have padding.  They are defined to have *contains a contiguously allocated non-empty set of N subobjects*

Comment: @ChrisMM If you had `std::array` then there could be padding since `std::array` is a class type and those are allowed to have padding.

Comment: Okay, I think I was confused because `char x[5]; int a;` can have padding between the two variables, and to me that padding belongs to `x`, and therefore takes more room than `sizeof( char ) * 5`. If that makes sense :)

Comment: @ChrisMM That padding belongs to neither of the objects.  Basically that padding belongs solely to the implementation.