# Tranpose of a matrix

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, transpose

I am trying to find the transpose of a given matrix A with `rows` rows and `cols` columns.
My try:

```
void GetTranspose(int* a, int rows, int cols, int* tr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            tr[i * cols + j] = a[j * rows + i];
        }
    }
}
```

The transpose of A has `cols` rows and `rows` columns. And that's why we want tr[i][j]=a[j][i]. I don't see where my mistake is. Maybe somewhere in the linearization of the matrices and where I set what tr[i][j] is.

That's how we invoke and use the function:

```
int a[4][3] = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {2, 3, 5},
    {7, 7, 7},
    {4, 9, 11}
};

int tr[3][4];

GetTranspose(&a[0][0], 4, 3, &tr[0][0]);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        cout << tr[i][j] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

I don't get why the result is:

[image]

Comment: Debug tip: add `std::cout << (i * cols + j) << " -> " << (j * rows + i) << '\n';` to your inner loop to see what indexes you are using.

Comment: C++ uses [row-major ordering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), the jth row and ith column should therefore be stored at `a[j * cols + i]`, but you're indexing it as `a[j * rows + i]`.

Comment: This is technical UB. using `int* a` argument of `GetTranspose`, you can only legally access the elements in the column where `a[0][0]` is the first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the way you are calculating the indices for the transpose matrix in your `GetTranspose` function. The correct calculation should be `tr[i * rows + j]` instead of `tr[i * cols + j]`.

Here's the corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void GetTranspose(int* a, int rows, int cols, int* tr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            tr[i * rows + j] = a[j * cols + i];  // Corrected index calculation
        }
    }
}

int a[4][3] =
{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {2, 3, 5},
    {7, 7, 7},
    {4, 9, 11}
};

int main()
{
    int tr[3][4];

    GetTranspose(&a[0][0], 4, 3, &tr[0][0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cout << tr[i][j] << " ";
        }

    cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code provided by you, the incorrect indexing leads to an incorrect mapping of elements from the original matrix to the transpose matrix.

After making this change, your code should work correctly, and you will get the expected transpose of the matrix `a`.

Now, the result should be the correct transpose of the matrix `a`.

---

**EDIT**

MORE DETAILED WALKTHROUGH

The goal of the `GetTranspose` function is to calculate the transpose of the matrix `a` and store the result in the matrix `tr`. The original code attempts to map the elements of `a` to the corresponding positions in `tr` using the formula `tr[i * cols + j] = a[j * rows + i]`.

**Here's the problem:**

- The correct formula should involve rows for the rows of the transpose matrix, not cols. The correct formula is `tr[i * rows + j] = a[j * cols + i]`.
- In the original code provided by you, using `tr[i * cols + j]` leads to incorrect indexing, resulting in incorrect mapping of elements.
- Like it is just the basics that you change rows into columns, not the other way around. On top of that, your code had every other thing fine except the transpose conversion definition.

**Correction:**
The correction involves changing the index calculation to use rows instead of cols for the rows of the transpose matrix. The corrected formula is `tr[i * rows + j] = a[j * cols + i]`.

Here's the corrected part in your code:

```
tr[i * rows + j] = a[j * cols + i];
```

This correction ensures that the elements from the original matrix `a` are correctly mapped to the positions in the transpose matrix `tr`, resulting in the correct transposition of the matrix.

Comment: I literally don't get why what you wrote works. Can you explain in to me? Thanks!

Comment: How did you come up with a way to find the correct indices?

Comment: I have updated the solution with more in-depth details and insight into what changes were made and what was wrong in the code. And about the problem; it is a pretty basic logic error that happens to every one of us from time to time. There was just one error in how you calculated the transpose in the code nothing else.

If my answer helped please consider it accepting as the answer. I hope this comment doesn't violate any stack rules.

Comment: Note that this is UB. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58699176/5282154) answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a pointer to the first element of a 2D array and assuming that the pointer can be used to access any element of the array is undefined behavior. Optimizers are allowed to assume that only the first column can be modified. This can cause hard to detect bugs. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58699176/5282154):

Here's proof it's UB.
https://godbolt.org/z/r497GjMWj

```
constexpr void foo(int *pa, int *pb, int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        *(pb + i) = *(pa + i);
}

consteval int foo1()
{
    int a[2][2]{ {1,2},{3,4} }; // Source array
    int b[2][2]{};              // Destination array
    foo(&a[0][0], &b[0][0], 2); // copy first column, OK
    foo(&a[0][0], &b[0][0], 4); // copy entire array, UB
    return b[1][1];     // return last element in array
}

int main()
{
    return foo1();
}
```

Remove the following line.

```
foo(&a[0][0], &b[0][0], 4); // copy entire array, UB
```

Now it compiles.
The legal way is to access the 2D arrays as the 2D objects they are:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <int R, int C>
void GetTranspose(int (&a)[R][C], int (&tr)[C][R])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++)
            tr[j][i] = a[i][j]; // transpose
}

int a[4][3] =
{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {2, 3, 5},
    {7, 7, 7},
    {4, 9, 11}
};

int main()
{
    int tr[3][4];
    GetTranspose(a,  tr);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cout << tr[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here, templatizing the function also will check the the Rows and Columns correspond to the Columns and Rows of the target matrix and you don't need to explicitly declare them.