# c++ - cast vector<T> to vector<array<T>>

Tags: c++, casting, stl

I have a std::vector of a simple datatype,
and would like to convert it in O(1) to a std::vector of std::arrays of the same simple datatype.

In particular both forms represent an array of all the vertex indices of a triangle mesh.
They both contain exactly the same number of indices, in exactly the same order, they just have different notions of boundaries.

So eg,

```
std::vector<uint32_t> X;
std::vector<std::array<uint32_t, 3>> = < ??? > (X);
```

Comment: What do you want the value of the arrays to be?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that in constant time. You'll have to copy the data; which is  `O(N)`

Comment: why do you need this transformation? Do you really need both structures? Cant you use one or the other?

Comment: i would rather write an iterator that lets you treat a `std::vector<uint32_t>` as if it was a `std::vector<std::array<uint32_t, 3>>` or vice versa, that shouldnt be too dificult to write and it avoids the explicit conversion completely

Comment: Something like `std::span`?

Comment: This is probably one of those infuriating situations where your information is likely contiguous and you can just wail away on `X.data()->data()` in the 80% case, but it's unavoidably undefined behavior because of strict aliasing rules and corner cases on exotic architectures. Here's a lawyer-ly QA for the same situation with a 2D `std::array`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269099/may-i-treat-a-2d-array-as-a-contiguous-1d-array/7273599#7273599

Comment: There might be an argument for casting the result of `data()` from one to the other, but certainly not for casting the whole `vector`. The `size` of a vector doesn't care how you reinterpret it's elements. An `array<int, 3>` is still exactly 1 element as far as the `vector` is concerned.

Comment: Please make the title match the actual question. The title asks the other way around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` is not the right tool for this.
`std::vector` is owning, thus if you want to reinterpret the memory allocated by 
`X` as a "vector" of arrays of ints, you should use a non-owning container such as `std::span`. Even then, you would have to use `reinterpret_cast`, which is recommended to avoid whenever possible.
Such as:

```cpp
std::span<std::array<uint32_t, 3>> points (reinterpret_cast<std::array<uint32_t, 3>*>(
    X.data()), X.size()/3);
```

Beware though, depending on the number of values in the std::array that you cast into, you might get into issues because of padding: consecutive arrays don't have to touch each other in memory.

For all of these reasons, I would instead recommend to either iterate over each third element or provide a wrapper class around `X`, which encapsulates the strong semantic bond between the owned data and the view on it.
That's also because the view is now ephemeral: it has to be recreated whenever `X` reallocates.

Comment: very helpful, thank you. thanks for pointing out the title/question discrepancy as well.