# Find the index of the largest element

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, matrix

The problem with my code is that it is not identifying my function, I am not sure if the function is incorrect or written with the wrong syntax. What I have tried is to create a new array for the location of the largest index but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void locateLargest(const double a[][4], int location[]);

const int ROW_SIZE = 3;
const int COLUMN_SIZE = 4;

int main(){

    int location [ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE];

    double matrix [ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE];

    double input;

    cout<<"Enter the array: "<< endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            cin>>input;
            matrix[i][j] =  input;
        }
    }

     for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            cout<< setw(4)<<matrix[i][j]<< " ";
        }
         cout<< endl;
    }

    locateLargest(matrix, location)
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to return a 3x4 matrix for just a row+column pair?

Comment: Why do you compare all elements with `a[0][0]`? You should compare all elements with the current max value. `location` should contain the position and not the value. You need something like `if(a[location[0]][location[1]] < a[i][j])

Comment: Don't you mean for location to be `int location[2]`?

Comment: You have a function named `locateLargest`. You may want to answer these questions. Do you want it to **return** the location or to **print** the location? If you want to return a location, what **is** a location (how you represent it)?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the max value's indices while iterating through the matrix.

```
void max_idx(const double (&arr)[RS][CS]) {
  double curr_max = arr[0][0];
  size_t max_i = 0, max_j = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < RS; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < CS; ++j) {
      if (curr_max < arr[i][j]) {
        curr_max = arr[i][j];
        max_i = i;
        max_j = j;
      }
    }
  }
  cout << "Largest value is at (i=" << max_i << ", j=" << max_j << ")\n";
}
```

[<kbd>`Demo`</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/7P15x6oEf)

Comment: A replacement for the two-level for-loop is using `std::max_element` and regard it as one large array, the get the row and column number by index  calculation

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin "and regard it as one large array" this would be undefined behaviour. In order to regard it as one large array, it needs to *be* one large array.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. The reason for undefined behaviour here that I can recall is that the argument is cast from some large 2-d array, then the memory layout does not continue for different rows. I think it's not the case in this question.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin It is not a question of memory layout. The behaviour is undefined simply because the standard says so. It is discussed in multiple posts on this site e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269099/may-i-treat-a-2d-array-as-a-contiguous-1d-array) and many of its duplicates (be sure to read all the answers and comments).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thank you so much, I have read the answers and comments, now I know it's a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to make sure that your code is consistent : in the prototype of your `locateLargest` function, `location` is a one-dimensional array but in your `main()` function it is a two-dimensional one.

This is how I would write this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void locateLargest(double** a, int* location);

const int ROW_SIZE = 3;
const int COLUMN_SIZE = 4;

int main()
{
    int location [2];
    double* matrix [ROW_SIZE];
    for(int s= 0; s< ROW_SIZE; s++)
    {
        matrix[s]= new double[COLUMN_SIZE];
    }

    double input;

    cout<<"Enter the array: "<< endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++)
        {
            cin>>input;
            matrix[i][j] =  input;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++)
        {
            cout<< setw(4)<<matrix[i][j]<< " ";
        }
         cout<< endl;
    }

    locateLargest(matrix, location);
}

void locateLargest(double** a, int* location)
{
    int i, j;
    double maxVal= a[0][0]; location[0]= location[1]= 0;

    for(i = 0;i < ROW_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++)
        {
           if(maxVal < a[i][j])
            {
               location[0] = i;
               location[1]= j;
               maxVal= a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "The location of the largest element is at ("<< location[0] << " , "<<
    location[1] <<" ) . it is : "<< maxVal<<endl;
}
```

`max` represents the maximum value of your matrix's elements, you first set it to be equal to the first element and then compare it to each element of the matrix. Each time you find an element that is larger than `max`, you assign his value to `max` and his position to `location` and at the end of the iterations, you have the largest value and his location.

Comment: Dangerously misleading answer. `double**` and `double [ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE]` are incompatible. Fortunately the code will not compile.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, there were also other errors on the code, I edited my answer and it compiles now. Sorry

Comment: So now it is just needlessly complicated instead of plain wrong. Why use `new`? What's the problem with fixed arrays? `int location [ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE];` works just fine.

Comment: Fixed arrays are fine in this case. And yes, it may be useless to use dynamic alocation but it could be a good practice for the cases where you don't know in advance the size of the array, I guess

Comment: The good practice is to use `std::vector`. Never `new` anything.